# Login Method in Django works fine with POSTMAN but with front end everything works except Login Method

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, fetch, django-login

I am new to React Js and want to connect my React app with Django.I had created **CustomUser for authentication purpose , login() for session and used rest_framework.auth.Token (Token)** for login Purpose. Now when I am sending **POST Request through POSTMAN** it **creates sessions properly** and return email and auth-token but when I am sending **POST Request with React Js** (Front End) Everything works properly (returns email and token) but **login method doesn't create sessions**, due to which user.is_authenticated returns False. How to solve this problem. Thanks in Advance.

My **views.py**

```
@csrf_exempt
def signin(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            token,created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)
        
            return JsonResponse({"Email":request.user.email,"Auth-token":token.key},safe=False)
        return render(request,'application/signup.html')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        email = data['email']
        print(email)
        b1 = email.replace("@","")
        password = data['password']
        print(password)
        user = authenticate(request,email=email,password=password)
        if user:
            location = str(pathlib.Path().absolute())+'\Camera\DatabaseImage\DatabaseImage\\' + b1 + '.jpg'
            print(location)
            answer = facedect(location)
            if answer=="Retry":
                messages.error(request,"Captured Image is not clear Please be in light")
                #React
                #return render(request,"application/signup.html")
                return JsonResponse("Captured Image is not clear Please be in light",safe=False)

            if answer == True:
                login(request,user)
                token,created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)
                messages.success(request,"Account created")
                #React 
                #return redirect('http://localhost:8000/homepage/')
                return JsonResponse({"Email":request.user.email,"Auth-token":token.key,"answer":"abhi login hua hai"},safe=False)
            else:
                print("Face Not Found")
                messages.error(request,"Face Not Found")
                #React
                #return render(request, 'Facebook.html')
                return JsonResponse("Face Not Found",safe=False)
        messages.error(request,"Invalid Email or Password")
        #React
        # return render(request,"application/signup.html")
        return JsonResponse("Not a Valid Email Address Or Password",safe=False)
```

my **React.js** Code

```
import { Redirect } from "react-router";
import "../Css/Navbar.css";
class Navbar extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state={
            email:'',
            password:''
        };
    }

    credential=(e)=>{
        let name = e.target.name
        let value = e.target.value
        this.setState({[name]:value})

    }

     login = (e)=>{
         let data1;
         e.preventDefault()
        console.log(this.state.email);
        console.log(this.state.password);
        fetch("http://localhost:8000/login/",{
            method:'POST',
            headers:{'Content-Type':'application/json'},
            body:JSON.stringify(this.state)

        }).then(data=>data.json()).then(data=>{
            data1 = data
            return console.log(data)}).catch(error=>console.log(error))
      
    }


render(){
    return(
        <>       
        <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark px3 py3 mt1">
            <a className="navbar-brand font-weight-bold"  >facebook</a>
            

                    <form className="ml-auto">
                    <div className="form-row">
                        <div className="col">
                        <input type="email" name="email" className="form-control form-control-sm mr-2" value={this.state.email} onChange={this.credential} placeholder="Email" />
                        </div>
                        <div className="col">
                        <input type="password" name="password" className="form-control form-control-sm mr-2" value={this.state.password} onChange={this.credential} placeholder="Password" />
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary btn-sm " onClick={this.login}>Login</button>
                    </div>
                    </form> 

        </nav>




        </>
    );
}}
export default Navbar;
```

Answer (score 0):

By default cross origin requests don't send the credentials (cookies, cookies, HTTP authentication entries, and TLS client certificates) along with the request. The server does set some variables in the users session but these are never used when you make subsequent requests to the server. To make requests with credentials to the server you need to set `credentials: 'include'` on your init options for `fetch` (do this for all requests you make to the server). Hence your `fetch` call should be like:

```
fetch("http://localhost:8000/login/",{
    credentials: 'include'
    method:'POST',
    headers:{'Content-Type':'application/json'},
    body:JSON.stringify(this.state)
})
```

Reference: [Sending a request with credentials included [developer.mozilla.org]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#sending_a_request_with_credentials_included)